# How do I to add gdb to cygwin?

Tags: debugging, gdb, cygwin

How do I add gdb to cygwin? I have downloaded gdb tar package for cygwin from sourceforge. When extracting it there were many files, so I pasted the gdb.exe file from the package into the bin folder of cygwin. However, it's not working.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you installed Cygwin the first time, you should have been given a setup program. If you have lost it, you can get it [from the Cygwin website](http://cygwin.com/). Run this again and select gdb for installation.

Comment: +1 to this. Many programs are hacked by the cygwin team, so trying to install them from their distributions doesn't work.

Comment: @bmargulies can you explain further. If a programme is hacked, can I still install it?

Comment: @timo What bmargulies means by "hacked" is that some programs need special configuration/changes from the officially distributed source to allow them to work appropriately in a Cygwin environment. You're welcome to build packages from source, but you'll probably end up doing a lot of work which has already been done by Cygwin contributurs. So you're probably better off using the Cygwin-distributed packages from the Cygwin website which have already been "tweaked" or "hacked" to make them work.

Comment: if you have apt-cyg installed, just run : apt-cyg install gdb

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs into this, I had the same issue and attempted to re-run the Cygwin installation package but couldn't find the `gdb` package.
Looks like the mirror I used was missing some packages! Solution is to use an "official" Cygwin mirror to get access to the full library of packages.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Cygwin (https://cygwin.com/), you have to select the **gdb and gdb-debuginfo packages** for installation. See required install packages for gdb at [https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/gdb-src.html]

[image]