# AddNumber function in program not working

Tags: c

I am having trouble understanding what I should do in the `AddNumber` function of my program. When the `AddNumber` function is called in `main` a pointer variable `previous` is created, and it takes the user's input and points it at the address of the variable `newNum`. I created an `if` statement for it to do that, but I was informed it doesn't do anything.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"


typedef struct A_NewNumber{
    struct A_NewNumber *next;
    double newNum;
} NewNumber;


NewNumber *AddNumber(NewNumber *previous, char *input){
    //char input[16];
    //double numEntered = 0;

    NewNumber *newNum = malloc(sizeof(NewNumber));
    sscanf(input, "%lf", &newNum->newNum);


    //sscanf(input, "%s", newNum->enterNumber);
    //numEntered = atof(input);

    /*if (previous != NULL){
        previous->newNum;
    }*/
    newNum->next = NULL;
    newNum->newNum = 0;
    return newNum;

}

void PrintList(NewNumber *start){
    NewNumber *currentNumber = start;
    int count = 0;

    while(currentNumber != NULL){
        count++;
        printf("Numbers:%lf\n", 
            currentNumber->newNum); 
        currentNumber = currentNumber->next;
    }
    printf("Total Numbers Entered%d\n", count);
}

void CleanUp(NewNumber *start){
    NewNumber *freeMe = start;
    NewNumber *holdMe = NULL;

    while(freeMe != NULL){
        holdMe = freeMe->next;
        free(freeMe);
        freeMe = holdMe;
    }
}

int main(){
    //indexNum = 0;
    char command[16];
    char input[16];
    //float userInput;
    NewNumber *userEnter = NULL;
    NewNumber *start = NULL;
    NewNumber *newest = NULL;

    while(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)){
        printf("Please enter a number->");
        printf("Enter 'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate");
        sscanf(input, "%s", command);
        if(newest == NULL){
            start = AddNumber(NULL, input);
            newest = start;
        }else{
            newest = AddNumber(newest, input);
        }if(strncmp(command, "print", 5) == 0){
            PrintList(start);
        }else if(strncmp(command, "quit", 4)== 0){
            printf("\n\nQuitting....\n");
            break;
           //userInput = enterNumber;
        }
    }
    CleanUp(start);
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program to see what it does at each step?

Comment: This is my third week learning C, and my programming skills are very minimal. I got it running, but debugging the program, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What IDE / compiler are you using?

Comment: i am using notepad ++ and cygwin

Comment: I'm not familiar with cygwin - this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779247/how-to-add-gdb-to-cygwin

Comment: Why read input and _then_ prompt for input?

Comment: I was under the impression the sscanf() function analyzes the user input data and then applies it to something.

Comment: You have: `sscanf(input, "%lf", &newNum->newNum);
…
    newNum->newNum = 0;` — the second statement undoes the good done by the first (though you should be checking the return value from `sscanf()` to know whether you got a number or not).

Comment: so i should be returning input?

Comment: No; you shouldn't be zeroing the `newNum->newNum` after you've initialized it with `sscanf()`.

Comment: 'NewNumber *AddNumber(NewNumber *previous, char *input){
 
 //char input[16];
 //double numEntered = 0;
     
 NewNumber *newNum = malloc(sizeof(NewNumber));
 sscanf(input, "%lf", &newNum->newNum);
 return newNum;
 
 //sscanf(input, "%s", newNum->enterNumber);
 //numEntered = atof(input);
 
 /*if (previous != NULL){
  previous->newNum;
 }*/
 //newNum->next = NULL;
 //newNum->newNum = 0;
 //return newNum;
 
} '
So this should work? @JonathanLeffler sorry i am not sure how to format it properly

Comment: How about you take your code and test it yourself?  There are limits to the formatting available in comments — C `//…EOL` comments aren't appropriate, for example.  I have certainly not attempted to run the code, but the change I see as minimally necessary is deleting one line.

Comment: I ran the program, but then I call the print function the program crashes and gives me a core dump error. @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1):

It was not that bad, was just in need of a bit of clean-up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    // ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!

typedef struct A_NewNumber {
  struct A_NewNumber *next;
  double newNum;
} NewNumber;


NewNumber *AddNumber(NewNumber * previous, char *input)
{
  int res;
  // allocate new node
  NewNumber *newNum = malloc(sizeof(NewNumber));

  if (newNum == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed in AddNUmber()\n");
    return previous;
  }
  // convert input string to float
  res = sscanf(input, "%lf", &newNum->newNum);
  if (res != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something bad happend in AddNUmber()\n");
    return previous;
  }
  // terminate that node
  newNum->next = NULL;
  // if this is NOT the first node
  // put new node to the end of the list
  if (previous != NULL) {
    previous->next = newNum;
  }
  // return pointer to new node at end of the list
  return newNum;
}

void PrintList(NewNumber * start)
{
  NewNumber *currentNumber = start;
  int count = 0;

  while (currentNumber != NULL) {
    count++;
    printf("Numbers:%lf\n", currentNumber->newNum);
    currentNumber = currentNumber->next;
  }
  printf("Total Numbers Entered %d\n", count);
}

void CleanUp(NewNumber * start)
{
  NewNumber *freeMe = start;
  NewNumber *holdMe = NULL;

  while (freeMe != NULL) {
    holdMe = freeMe->next;
    free(freeMe);
    freeMe = holdMe;
  }
}

int main()
{
  char input[16];
  NewNumber *start = NULL;
  NewNumber *newest = NULL;
  int res;

  // infinite loop
  while (1) {
    // give advise
    printf("Please enter a number or\n");
    printf("'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate\n");
    // get input from user
    res = scanf("%s", input);
    if (res != 1) {
      if (res == EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Got EOF, bailing out\n");
        break;
      } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "something bad happend, bailing out\n");
        break;
      }
    }
    // check if a command was given
    if (strncmp(input, "print", 5) == 0) {
      PrintList(start);
      continue;
    } else if (strncmp(input, "quit", 4) == 0) {
      printf("\n\nQuitting....\n");
      break;
    }
    // otherwise gather numbers
    if (newest == NULL) {
      start = AddNumber(NULL, input);
      if (start == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "AddNumber returned NULL\n");
        break;
      }
      newest = start;
    } else {
      newest = AddNumber(newest, input);
      if (newest == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "AddNumber returned NULL\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  CleanUp(start);
  return 0;
}
```

You should really make a habit of checking *all* returns and if you don't: be able to give a *good* reason why you didn't.

Don't forget to switch on *all* warnings your compiler offers. Even if you don't understand them now, Google might have an answer and if not some people here do (in that order, thank you).

Comment: i know this might be a lot to ask but would you mind explaining to me what you did? like what is the purpose of res? @deamentiaemundi

Comment: Sorry, I see you explain in the comments, but I'm sure I will have questions. @deamentiaemundi

Comment: @ericeric `res` is an `int` I use to hold the return value of `scanf` for later check, e.g.: test for `EOF` (end of file/input).

Comment: I now have to add all the numbers I take in and give an average of them is it newNum that holds all the numbers or is it currentNumber?

Comment: @ericeric you have a number that prints the list. You can use that function and change it to sum the numbers up instead of printing them. Do the arithmetic/geometric/square/harmonic mean and return that number.

Comment: thank you for your help i will try this out and see what i come up with