# How to install debugger in Cygwin and use gdb for debugging C programs?

Tags: gdb, cygwin

I have Cygwin and want to debug a C program. The gdb command gives 'command not found' error message. How do I get the gdb command to work?

Is there something else I need to install during the Cygwin installion?

**Error in Cygwin Terminal**:
**-bash: gdb: command not found**

Comment: Assuming you haven't already installed gdb I would start here first https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779250/1878262

Comment: @Sherif - I've re-installed Cygwin and made sure I checked the GNU Debugger for installation. It still doesn't work... same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing Cygwin (https://cygwin.com/), you have to **select the gdb and gdb-debuginfo packages** for installation. See required install packages for gdb at [https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/gdb-src.html]

See below:
[image]

Comment: The gdb-debuginfo package should not be necessary for gdb itself to work.

Comment: @ssbssa It didn't work until I installed both.